# TShape Lazarus, nothing display

Tags: canvas, drawing, shapes, lazarus

I'm trying to draw on a TShape via the Canvas, but, nothing display.

```
procedure TController.DrawGrind;
begin
  ShowMessage('I try do draw something');

  with FView.Shape1 do
  begin
    Canvas.MoveTo(Left, Top);
    Canvas.Pen.Width:= 5;
    Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
    Canvas.Pen.Color:= clRed;
    Canvas.Brush.Color:= clRed;
    Canvas.LineTo(Left, Width);
  end;

  FView.Shape1.Refresh;

end;
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're calling `Refresh` method. This method immediately forces the control to repaint. Draw your painting in the `OnPaint` event method instead and call just that `Refresh` or `Invalidate` on that shape object to force it to trigger the `OnPaint` event:

```
procedure TController.DrawGrind;
begin
  ShowMessage('I try do draw something');
  // if you use Refresh instead of Invalidate, the control will be forced
  // to repaint itself immediately
  FView.Shape1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.Shape1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Shape1.Canvas.Pen.Width := 5;
  Shape1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Shape1.Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  Shape1.Canvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
  Shape1.Canvas.LineTo(Shape1.ClientWidth, Shape1.ClientHeight);
end;
```

In your original code you were also trying to draw on quite weird position. Canvas coordinates starts at `[0; 0]` and goes to `[Control.ClientWidth; Control.ClientHeight]`.

Comment: See the update. And you can't see anything most probably because you're drawing on the coordinates of the relative position of the shape to its parent. Canvas coordinates starts on `[0; 0]` to `[Control.ClientWidth; Control.ClientHeight]`.